# Spring Boot: Perform encryption/decryption using Annotation: MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a requirement where I have to encrypt a field before saving in the database and decrypt it while retrieving it. The fields that should be encrypted should be custom annotated.

I am using spring-boot with MongoDB for this.

Example:

```
Class Person {

Long ID;

String userName;

String password;

@EncryptThisField
String firstName;

@EncryptThisField
String lastName;

... SETTER and GETTERS

}
```

Based on annotation my setter should set encrypted value(and save to database) and getter should return decrypted value(and retrieve from database).

Any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: Have you done any research? Tried anything? What happened?

Comment: I was going through tutorials and all of them had a method for processing the annotation. Since in this case, I have to save and retrieve data from mongodb, I am not sure if I should override all the save and retrieve methods that is used there.

Answer (score 0):

you should create two functional-interface. One to encrypt and other decrypt. use the annotation on the setter and getter methods instead of on the field.